# How can I make browser scale image frames according to CSS before loading actual images into frames?

Tags: html, css, image, lazy-loading, loading

In a web page I have several images which are stacked on top of each other. The CSS for the images are

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.66em;
}
```

All images have proper height and width specified in the html img tag.

When the page loads on a slow connection I would like the frames where the images will appear to scale **before the actual images are loaded into them**. This because it sometimes looks like this:

```
[----------------]
[  Loaded image  ]
[----------------]

[ Not loaded image ]

[----------------]
[  Loaded image  ]
[----------------]
```

where the loaded image have the right size but the not loaded one are still just a row where the `alt=text` is shown.

[image: Loading images]

Then, when the middle of the three loads it swells to the right size and moves the others.

I would like the appearance and loading to be the same as it would have been without the CSS: The empty frames where the image will appear shows at the right pixelsize, it is then filled with the image.

Please be aware that this of course is a problem only on slow connection, the images are not that big really.

The images are progressive JPGs.

**I would like to:**

- Scale image frames according to css setting before filling them up with the image.
- Load images in sequential order, beginning with the ones on top and continuing down the page.

Using the great [Lazyloading plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) could of course be a solution, but it seems overkill.

I could also use javascript to detect window width and then change the `width` and `height` in the html tag, but this seems unnecessary.

I would prefer a solution where I don't have to alter the code for the images themselves. Preferably only with css if this is achievable.

Looking much forward to your thoughts! Thanks for reading this long post :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order which objects in the page are loaded can to my knowledge not be controlled in any other way than by using a javascript. Different browsers also load the page differently:

Firefox tend to load one progressive JPEG after another, while Chrome starts loading in all of them simultaneously.

The Lazyload plugin for jQuery could be a solution, it does the placeholder and scaling of the images good, but it disables the progressive downloading of the JPEGs.

I **think** that putting `height: auto;` in the css for the image makes an improvement (image frame gets right size faster), but it's a marginal difference and I'm not sure.

Solution would be to write a javascript which uses a placeholder image first, and then sequentially reads in the images and allows them to display progressively.

Thankful for further opinions on how this script could be written or different solutions to my problem!